# Can LibraryLink receive and output a list of strings?

Tags: librarylink

I need to use libraryLink to process a list of strings, I haven't found a suitable example, confused about the types of the arguments and return types. Does libraryLink directly support it, which one is suitable for me?

Comment: Some more notes: My LTemplate package makes it a little bit easier to extend Mathematica with LibraryLink, and has a very basic streams-like interface to return data  with MathLink-based passing. There is an example in the LinkObject subdirectory of the documentation which shows how to receive a list of strings. The same will also work in the reverse, basically an `std::vector<std::string> mylist; mlink << mylist;`.

Comment: Recently, Wolfram released a similar C++ package that also simplifies working with LibraryLink. I am not familiar with this, and I do not know if it has any features to help with your problem. But I definitely recommend that you take a look. https://wolframresearch.github.io/LibraryLinkUtilities/ If you find that it already has a solution, please write your own answer.

Comment: If you can set up your library using [LibraryLinkUtilities](https://github.com/WolframResearch/LibraryLinkUtilities), then it is as easy as following [this documentation example](https://wolframresearch.github.io/LibraryLinkUtilities/modules/containers.html#llu-genericdatalist).

Comment: @JasonB. Ah, so that's where DataStore is effectively documented ... I never knew what it was, and whether it could be used for this task. It's a pity it's not officially documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Use MathLink for argument passing/return. Read "LinkObject Arguments and Result" in the LibraryLink documentation. Anything that can be represented as a Mathematica expression can be sent through MathLink, so this is the easiest way. The drawback is (1) performance (2) some parts of the MathLink API which would allow better performance are not documented. ([This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180706/12) is an example of a situation where the lack of documentation caused a bit of frustration.)
2. Serialize the list of strings yourself in some way, and then deserialize in Mathematica. For example:

   - If your strings have no newlines, you can use newlines as a separator and concatenate into a single string. Then use `StringSplit` in Mathematica.
   - If your strings have no null characters, you can use the null character as separator and encode the string into a byte NumericArray.
   - You could just encode everything into JSON and use `` Developer`ReadRawJSONString `` to deserialize.
   - You could encode everything into WXF, transfer as a NumericArray, then deserialize with either `BinaryDeserialize` or `` Developer`ReadWXFByteArray ``. You will need to implement your own WFX writer. This is not infeasible, but it'll take a bit of work. See the [WXF Specification](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WXFFormatDescription.html). Back in 2018, a Wolfram developer mentioned that they might make a C WXF encoder library available, but I haven't heard anything since then. See [WXF encoder library for C++](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184332/12)
3. Store your list of strings on the C side, and retrieve each list element with a separate function call, using a final function call to clean up. I think this is a good approach when you want to return a small, fixed number of heterogeneous data structures. I would not do this if I had to return an indeterminate number of homogeneous pieces of data.

If you don't need top performance, my recommendation is to go with MathLink argument passing. I use this for many functions in my IGraph/M package. For a few other functions, which transfer a very large amount of data (thus the bottleneck is actually data transfer), I used a naive serialization of ragged integer matrices into a flat integer list.

See also:

- [MathLink (WSTP) vs LibraryLink performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91887/12)
- [Returning multiple results from a LibraryLink function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31545/12)

Answer (score 11):

Some time ago I wrote a post on community.wolfram.com about integrating C++ with the Wolfram Language using a library called LibraryLink Utilities (LLU). The post can be found here

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2133603

I recommend reading the whole thing if you are interested in the topic. Below I will paste the section about exchanging lists of data between C/C++ and WL, which I hope answers your question directly. The text below contains references to LLU which may not be clear if you are not familiar with the library but you can simply skip those and focus on the parts that refer to the "pure" LibraryLink.

### Passing and returning heterogeneous lists

LibraryLink has a fixed list of types that can be used as library function arguments and return values. For instance, see the "Details and Options" section in
the documentation of [LibraryFunctionLoad](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html). As you can see, it is straightforward to
pass an array of numeric data, a string or an image but already sending a list of images is hard. One can conform all the images and transfer them via
LibraryLink as a single `Image3D` but this puts a toll on efficiency. Sending a list of strings is simply impossible without tricks or workarounds.

This topic has been brought up by the community quite a few times:

- [Returning multiple results from a LibraryLink function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/returning-multiple-results-from-a-librarylink-function)
- [Is it possible to let LibraryLink return multiple results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121825/is-it-possible-to-let-librarylink-return-multiple-results)
- [LibraryFunctionLoad for multivariate C++ function containing several arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128723/libraryfunctionload-for-multivariate-c-function-containing-several-arguments)
- [LibraryFunctionLoad with variable number of arguments](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366849)
- [Working with a variable number of arguments in LibraryLink](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/190560)

It turns out that the solution to this problem already exists in LibraryLink and is called `DataStore`. The only problem is that for now it remains
undocumented. Below is a quick glimpse of what `DataStore` is, which should also help understand the C++ wrappers of `DataStore` that LLU has to offer.

[image: DataStore structure]

As can be seen in the picture, `DataStore` is a simple unidirectional linked list but with limited functionality exposed, compared for instance to
`std::forward_list`. The API provided in the Wolfram Library allows for

- creating an empty `DataStore`
- copying or deleting existing `DataStore`
- appending new nodes at the end
- iterating over nodes
- obtaining the length of the store (in constant time)

Each node of the `DataStore` carries a value of type `MArgument`, which is a union type of all types that LibraryLink can handle as function arguments or
return values. The `MArgument` union include `DataStore` which means that the store can be nested. Additionally, every node contains an optional "name" which
can be any string. Names do not have to be unique.

A simple library function that takes a list of strings (in the form of a `DataStore`) and returns a new list with each of the input strings reversed,
implemented in pure LibraryLink may look like this:

```c
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int StringsReversedLibraryLink(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {

    // get DataStore which is the first input argument to the library function
    DataStore ds_in = MArgument_getDataStore(Args[0]);

    mint length = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStore_getLength(ds_in);

    // create new DataStore to hold the result
    DataStore ds_out = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->createDataStore();
    if (ds_out == nullptr) {
        // error handling
    }
    
    // start traversing the DataStore from the first node
    DataStoreNode dsn = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStore_getFirstNode(ds_in);
    while (dsn != nullptr) {
        MArgument node_data;
        if (libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getData(dsn, &node_data) != 0) {
           // error handling and cleanup
        }
        if (libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getDataType(dsn) != MType_UTF8String) {
           // error handling and cleanup
        }
        // reverse the order of characters in the string and push to the output DataStore
        std::string_view s {MArgument_getUTF8String(node_data)};
        std::string outStr(s.rbegin(), s.rend());    // create reversed copy
        libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStore_addString(ds_out, outStr.data());

        // move to the next node
        dsn = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getNextNode(dsn);
    }
    // set the newly created DataStore as the result of this library function call
    MArgument_setDataStore(Res, ds_out);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

It is clear how to operate on `DataStore`s in C code now, but the Wolfram Language side of LibraryLink also uses a representation of this structure and it is
defined as follows:

```
Developer`DataStore[node_expr$1, node_expr$2, ..., node_expr$n]
```

where each `node_expr` is of the form `string -> expr` or just `expr` with an extra requirement that `expr` must be an expression supported in LibraryLink.

For example, `` Developer`DataStore["abc", "de", "f"] `` passed to the function implemented above would result in `` Developer`DataStore["cba", "ed", "f"] `` being
returned from the library.

LLU provides two direct wrappers over `DataStore`: `LLU::GenericDataList` and `LLU::DataList<T>`. The former equips `DataStore` with a proper container
interface including methods like `push_back()`, `front()`, `back()` or `length()`. It also offers easier iteration over the list with `begin()` and `end()`.

The second wrapper is templated with a node type and should be used whenever we expect a homogeneous `DataStore` (with all nodes of the same type). The types
that can be passed as template parameter are not the raw LibraryLink types included in the MArgument union but rather their LLU counterparts. For convenience,
they are enclosed in `LLU::NodeType` namespace with following members:

```cpp
/// Boolean type, corresponds to True or False in the Wolfram Language
using Boolean = bool;

/// Machine integer type
using Integer = mint;

/// Double precision floating point type
using Real = double;

/// Complex number type, bitwise-compatible with mcomplex defined in WolframLibrary.h
using Complex = std::complex<double>;

/// Tensor stands for a GenericTensor - type agnostic wrapper over MTensor
using Tensor = MContainer<MArgumentType::Tensor>;

/// SparseArray type corresponds to the "raw" MSparseArray as LLU does not have its own wrapper for this structure yet
using SparseArray = MSparseArray;

/// NumericArray stands for a GenericNumericArray - type agnostic wrapper over MNumericArray
using NumericArray = MContainer<MArgumentType::NumericArray>;

/// Image stands for a GenericImage - type agnostic wrapper over MImage
using Image = MContainer<MArgumentType::Image>;

/// String values from LibraryLink (char*) are wrapped in std::string_view
using UTF8String = std::string_view;

/// DataStore stands for a GenericDataList - type agnostic wrapper over DataStore
using DataStore = MContainer<MArgumentType::DataStore>;
```

Additionally, there is also `LLU::NodeType::Any` which can be used to make `LLU::DataList` work with a heterogeneous `DataStore`. `LLU::DataList` compared to
`LLU::GenericDataList` provides more iteration options (iteration over node values or node names only) and a function to immediately create a `std::vector` out
of the stored values.

Let us implement the same function as above using `LLU::GenericDataList`:

```cpp
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int StringsReversedGeneric(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    auto err = LLU::ErrorCode::NoError;
    try {
        using NodeT = LLU::NodeType::UTF8String;

        LLU::MArgumentManager mngr(libData, Argc, Args, Res);
        auto dsIn = mngr.getGenericDataList(0);
        GenericDataList dsOut;
        // iterate over the GeneridDataList with a range-based for loop
        for (auto node : dsIn) {
            // we are dealing with generic DataList, so we need to be explicit about the actual node type
            std::string_view s = node.as<NodeT>();
            std::string reversed {s.rbegin(), s.rend()};    // create reversed copy
            dsOut.push_back(std::string_view(reversed));    // passing a view is fine because DataStore will copy the string immediately
        }
        
        mngr.set(dsOut);
    } catch (const LLU::LibraryLinkError& e) {
        err = e.which();
    } catch (...) {
        err = LLU::ErrorCode::FunctionError;
    }
    return err;
```

In the function above we know that all nodes should contain strings, so we could use `LLU::DataList<LLU::NodeType::UTF8String>` instead of the generic data
list. The code would stay almost the same, except we could simply call `node.value()` to get the corresponding `std::string_view`.

For a different example, consider a function `SeparateKeysAndValue` that takes a data store of named complex numbers and separates it into two data stores:
one holding names of the original data store and another one with values. For instance,

```
Developer`DataStore["a" -> 1 + 2.5 * I, "b" -> -3. - 6.I, 2I, "d" -> -4]
```

would be transformed into

```
Developer`DataStore[
    "Keys" -> Developer`DataStore["a", "b", "", "d"], 
    "Values" -> Developer`DataStore[1. + 2.5 * I, -3. - 6.I, 2.I, -4.]
]
```

The implementation of such library function may look as follows:

```cpp
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int SeparateKeysAndValues(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    LLU::MArgumentManager mngr(libData, Argc, Args, Res);

    auto dsIn = mngr.getDataList<LLU::NodeType::Complex>(0);
    DataList<LLU::NodeType::UTF8String> keys;
    DataList<LLU::NodeType::Complex> values;

    // we use structured bindings to immediately split each node into name and value
    for (auto [name, value] : dsIn) {
        keys.push_back(name);
        values.push_back(value);
    }

    DataList<GenericDataList> dsOut; // the output type is a DataList of DataLists
    dsOut.push_back("Keys", std::move(keys));
    dsOut.push_back("Values", std::move(values));

    mngr.set(dsOut);
}
```

Instead of a single loop with structured bindings, we could also make two passes over the input data list:

```cpp
DataList<LLU::NodeType::UTF8String> keys;
for (auto name : LLU::NameAdaptor {dsIn}) {
    keys.push_back(name);
}
    
DataList<LLU::NodeType::Complex> values;
for (auto value : LLU::ValueAdaptor {dsIn}) {
    values.push_back(value);
}
```

Notice that we use iterator adaptors `LLU::NameAdaptor` and `LLU::ValueAdaptor` to iterate over a specific property of the nodes (either name or value,
respectively).

Comment: Great answer, big +1!

Comment: Great answer! "The only problem is that for now it remains undocumented" That is indeed a big problem and I hope this will change soon. But this answer goes a long way to remedy the problem. Do you have any insights into performance compared to other possible methods I mentioned?

Comment: @Szabolcs I did a simple test once to compare the speed of raw DataStore, DataStore wrapper in LLU and WSTP wrapper in LLU, the code was sending 300k random strings to the library, reverting the order of characters in each string and then sending back to WL. WSTP turned out to be ~2.5x slower than DataStore. But this is far from proper benchmarking. My guess is that all workarounds based on serialization might be even slower.

Comment: @rafalc Thanks for the reponse. I responded yesterday, but it seems it didn't go through. I don't think naive serialization would be slower than WSTP. See some of my messages [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/575100): in some cases, even serializing to JSON (which I would expect to be quite slow) does better than WSTP.

Comment: I'll definitely try this out and do some benchmarking. The most performance-critical application I have returns a list of integer vectors of various sizes. I really wonder if it can do better than the naive serialization I used there (I doubt it, but I'm hopeful—let's see!)

Comment: One important question for me: which is the earliest version where DataStore is available? Is it available in 11.0, which is the earliest version I need to support at the moment? (I can see that it is, but does it work the same way as it does in 12.3? That's not so trivial to test.)

Comment: @Szabolcs DataStore is present in 11.0 but essentially it can only be used with AsynchronousTasks and not as an argument to LibraryLink functions. This functionality has been added in M12.0.

Comment: @rafalc I'm not sure how to specify to `LibraryFunctionLoad` that I expect a DataStore to be input or output from my function. Is there something like a `LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "fun_name", {DataStore}, DataStore]`?

Comment: @iago-lito almost correct, "DataStore" should be a String, so `LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "fun_name", {"DataStore"}, "DataStore"]`

Comment: Haha! I had tried that, but this is the embarrassing moment where I realize that I'm actually working with Mathematica 11.3 and there is only support for this approach since 12.0 X) Sorry for bothering, and thank you anyway. I'll have to stick with the good'ol way then and write one dedicated function to retrieve each resulting value :)

Comment: Funny, I note the `"DataStrore"` [cannot accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx1E0.png) an empty `List`. Or I missed something [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271936/21532)

Answer (score 1):

Related my [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271362/21532). I post a `FunctionCompile` version here for a list of strings:

As the output of `FunctionCompileExportString[Typed[x, "ListVector"["String"]] |-> x]`. We can know the memory structure used for transmission is
[image]
So we build a struct as the hint:

```
struct mmaStr {
    char* utf8string;
    umint length1;
    umint length2;
    umint refcount;
};

struct ManagedArray {
    mmaStr** data;
    mint length;
};

struct FixedArray {
    ManagedArray data;
    umint refcount;
};

struct StringList {
    FixedArray* data;
    umint refcount;
};
```

This structure can be used to transfer string lists between MMA and c++. So we can implement a `getReverseStrings` like this:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include\"WolframIOLibraryFunctions.h\"
#include\"WolframCompileLibrary.h\"
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct mmaStr {
    char* utf8string;
    umint length1;
    umint length2;
    umint refcount;
};

struct ManagedArray {
    mmaStr** data;
    mint length;
};

struct FixedArray {
    ManagedArray data;
    umint refcount;
};

struct StringList {
    FixedArray* data;
    umint refcount;
public:

    mint size() {
        return data->data.length;
    }

    mmaStr** begin() {
        return data->data.data;
    }

    mmaStr** end() {
        return this->begin() + this->size();
    }

    mint nelems() {
        mint len = 0;
        for (auto tensor : *this) {
            len += tensor->length2;
        }
        return len;
    }

    vector<string> toVec() {
        vector<string> vec;
        for (auto tensor : *this) {
            string sss = tensor->utf8string;
            vec.push_back(sss);
        }
        return vec;
    }

    void getReverseStrings() {
        for (auto tensor : *this) {
            string_view view(tensor->utf8string);
            string rev{ view.rbegin(),view.rend() };
            copy(rev.cbegin(), rev.cend(), tensor->utf8string);
        }
    }
};

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT StringList* reverseStrings(StringList* stringlist) {
    stringlist->getReverseStrings();
    //(stringlist.refcount)++;
    return stringlist;
}", ToString[Unique["dll"]], Language -> "C++", "CompileOptions"->"/std:c++17"];

dec = LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun -> "reverseStrings", 
   lib, {"ListVector"::["String"]} -> "ListVector"::["String"]];
fc = FunctionCompile[dec, 
  Function[Typed[lis, "ListVector"::["String"]], fun[lis]]]
```

[image]

```
fc[{"programme", "abc", "cplus2022", "Project10"}]
```

> `{"emmargorp", "cba", "2202sulpc", "01tcejorP"}`