# Why the Debug .dll is work normall but the Release .dll is crash in librarylink?

Tags: crash, debugging, c++, function-compile

The `Catenate` is very slow in `FunctionCompile`. So I want to use the *librarylink* to make a `.dll` function to replace it. This is the current c++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
#include <limits>
#include "WolframCompileLibrary.h"


using namespace std;

struct ManagedArray {
    MTensor* data;
    mint length;
};

struct FixedArray {
    ManagedArray data;
    mint refcount;
};

struct RaggedTensor {
    FixedArray* data;
    mint refcount;
public:
    mint size() {
        return data->data.length;
    }

    MTensor* begin() {
        return data->data.data;
    }

    MTensor* end() {
        return this->begin() + this->size();
    }

    mint nelems() {
        mint len = 0;
        for (auto tensor : *this) {
            len += tensor->nelems;
        }
        return len;
    }

    MTensor toMTensor() {
        mint dims[] = { this->nelems() };
        MTensor Res = new st_MNumericArray[1];
        Res->dims = dims;
        Res->prec = -numeric_limits<mreal>::infinity();
        Res->rank = 1;
        Res->tensor_property_type = 3;
        Res->flags = UBIT32(131);
        Res->data_type = 10;
        Res->nelems = this->nelems();
        Res->data = (void*) new mreal[Res->nelems];
        auto pRes = (mreal*)Res->data;
        for (auto tensor : *this) {
            auto ptensor = (mreal*)tensor->data;
            copy(ptensor, ptensor + tensor->nelems, pRes);
            pRes += tensor->nelems;
        }
        return Res;
    }
};

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT MTensor Catenate(RaggedTensor inlis){
    inlis.toMTensor();
    (inlis.refcount)++;
    return inlis.toMTensor();
}
```

But the crazy thing is that I found that the `.dll` compiled by **Debug** mode is fine:
[image]

```
dec = LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun -> "Catenate", 
   "D:/programme/cplus2022/Project1/x64/Debug/Project1.dll", {"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]} -> 
    "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]];
fcplus = FunctionCompile[dec, Function[{Typed[raglis, 
     "ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]]}, fun[raglis]]]
data = N[{{5, 9, 3}, {7, 9}, {9, 11, 8, 33}}];
Table[fcplus[data], 10] // Column
```

[image]

But when I compile it by **Release** mode, The MMA kernel will crash:
[image]

```
dec = LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun -> "Catenate", 
   "D:/programme/cplus2022/Project1/x64/Release/Project1.dll", {"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]} -> 
    "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]];
fcplus = FunctionCompile[dec, Function[{Typed[raglis, 
     "ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]]}, fun[raglis]]]
data = N[{{5, 9, 3}, {7, 9}, {9, 11, 8, 33}}];
Table[fcplus[data], 10] // Column
```

What's happen? It's a bug of the kernel? Is there any workaround to avoid it?

---

BTY, the `` CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary `` just can compile code with **Release** mode even if you add an option `Debug -> True` as I know.

Comment: Since you're on Visual Studio, can you confirm the configurations for Release mode are the same as Debug mode?

Comment: @BenIzd I'm pretty sure. Is the **Debug** and **Release** both working on your pc? If you can solve this problem, I am willing to give you another 500 points. :)

Comment: Mine crashed too, I was as surprised as you, but we're not the first to see [this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186237/11965951). [It seems](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/) uninitialized variables in release and debug mode in Visual Studio are different. I did manage to make the Release mode work by adding `Res->refcount = 2;`. Note that with/without change the code above leaks memory (also I couldn't understand `inlis.toMTensor();` existence)

Comment: All of these aside, on a large ragged list, your code (release mode) was almost 10 times faster than `Catenate`. Kudos to you.

Comment: @BenIzd You provide a very good clue, thank you very very much, but I can only seem to measure that `fcplus` is about $4$ times faster than the built-in `Catenate`

Comment: On `data = Table[RandomReal[{0, 2^10}, RandomInteger[{10, 500}]], 1000]` it was `9.1` but I've seen larger gap (on AMD Ryzen 3950X).

Comment: I removed the "bugs" tag.  Writing C code that crashes the kernel is very easy to do but in no way is this a Mathematica bug.

Comment: @JasonB. Hi, note the struct `MTensor` is a private class of `Wolfram` linker.  And the crash is caused by the inability to initialize the struct. So I still think the `bug` tag is appropriate

Comment: @BenIzd Do you think I have add a `bug` tag for this post?

Comment: @yode To my eye (a pre-amateur in this domain) this would be more about the difference in Release vs Debug mode in the compiler rather than something related to Mathematica. (don't know about the leak though)

Comment: @yode I don't think this is a bug. Without Visual Studio to try your example, I suspect this is related to memory management. When using LibraryLink, users need to [take care of "ownership" of MTensor](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithWolframLanguage.html#97446640), I think similarly when using the new compiler, ["Managed"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/compiledtype/Managed.html) should play the same roll. (...)

Comment: For example, maybe your debugger held a reference to the tensor so it's not collected. But in your release mode that's not true so you were accessing illegal memory.

Comment: Also, according to tag info, our **bugs** tag [_"should not be used when asking new questions"_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info). I believe WRI tracks the tag on this site regularly, if unexpected behaviours are all marked as bugs, that could dilute the significance of the tag and the importance of those real bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I use `WolframLibraryData` to initialize the `MTensor` now, I have solved the crash bug. And don't leak memory anymore：

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib=CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include<vector>
#include \"WolframRTL.h\"

using namespace std;

WolframLibraryData libData = WolframLibraryData_new(WolframLibraryVersion);

struct ManagedArray {
    MTensor* data;
    mint length;
};

struct FixedArray {
    ManagedArray data;
    umint refcount;
};

struct RaggedTensor {
    FixedArray* data;
    umint refcount;
public:
    mint size() {
        return data->data.length;
    }

    MTensor* begin() {
        return data->data.data;
    }

    MTensor* end() {
        return this->begin() + this->size();
    }

    mint total_nelems() {
        mint len = 0;
        for (auto tensor : *this) {
            len += tensor->nelems;
        }
        return len;
    }

    template <typename T>
    MTensor toFlattenMTensor() {
        mint dims[] = { this->total_nelems() };
        MTensor Res;
        libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 1, dims, &Res);
        auto pRes = (T*)Res->data;
        for (MTensor tensor : *this) {
            auto ptensor = (T*)tensor->data;
            copy(ptensor, ptensor + tensor->nelems, pRes);
            pRes += tensor->nelems;
        }

        return Res;
    }
};

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT MTensor Catenate(RaggedTensor inlis) {
    WolframLibraryData_free(libData);
    return inlis.toFlattenMTensor<mreal>();
}","Catenatefile","Language"->"C++","Libraries"->"WolframRTL_Kernel.lib"];

dec=LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun->"Catenate",lib,{"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64",1]]}->"PackedArray"::["Real64",1]];
fcplus=FunctionCompile[dec,Function[{Typed[raglis,"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64",1]]]},fun[raglis]]]
```

Now we can use it now. It's nearly 5 times faster than the built-in `Catenate`:

```
lis = Table[ResourceFunction["RandomSplit"][RandomReal[255, 1000], 10], 100000];
AbsoluteTiming[a = Catenate /@ lis;]
AbsoluteTiming[b = fcplus /@ lis;]
a == b
```

> {2.37345, Null}

> {0.348485, Null}

> True

Comment: That does not want to print True in 13.3. It prints a long list. The example below works though.

Answer (score 2):

Add a *librarylink* version, which based on `DataStore`. It don't crash and doesn't leak memory anymore:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib=CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include \"WolframIOLibraryFunctions.h\"
#include \"WolframCompileLibrary.h\"

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int Catenate(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument* Args, MArgument Res) {
    DataStore ds_in = MArgument_getDataStore(Args[0]);
    DataStoreNode dsn = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStore_getFirstNode(ds_in);

    mint n = 0;
    while (dsn != nullptr) {
        MArgument node_data;
        libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getData(dsn, &node_data);

        MTensor lis = MArgument_getMTensor(node_data);
        n += lis->nelems;

        dsn = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getNextNode(dsn);
    }

    MTensor result;
    mint dims[] = { n };
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 1, dims, &result);
    mreal* presult = MTensor_getRealDataMacro(result);
    mint th = 0;

    dsn = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStore_getFirstNode(ds_in);
    while (dsn != nullptr) {
        MArgument node_data;
        libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getData(dsn, &node_data);

        MTensor lis = MArgument_getMTensor(node_data);
        mreal* plis = MTensor_getRealDataMacro(lis);

        for (int i = 0; i < lis->nelems; i++) {
            presult[th++] = plis[i];
        }
        dsn = libData->ioLibraryFunctions->DataStoreNode_getNextNode(dsn);
    }

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, result);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
","Catenatefile","Language"->"C++"]

fun = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "Catenate", {"DataStore"}, {Real, 1}]
```

It's nearly 5 times faster than the built-in function:

```
lis=DeleteCases[Table[ResourceFunction["RandomSplit"][RandomReal[255,1000],10],100000],{},{2}];
AbsoluteTiming[b=Catenate/@lis;]
AbsoluteTiming[a=fun[Developer`DataStore@@#]&/@lis;]
a == b
```

> {3.49999, Null}

> {0.775869, Null}

> True